# MongoDB Atlas import json file - getting an error

Tags: mongodb

I am experimenting with MongoDB atlas and also a local install of Mongo DB.   I've had great success with importing a local 5mb JSON file into my local MongoDB install, but get the following error when I try to import to MongoDB Atlas:

import command I run on command line:

```
mongoimport --host mongodb+srv://<USER>:<PASS>@cluster0-<*****>mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true --ssl -u <USER> -p '<PASS>' --authenticationDatabase admin --db <DB_NAME> --collection <COLLECTION_NAME> --drop --file < FULL PATH TO LOCAL JSON FILE>
```

The error I get back:

```
2019-05-19T20:54:55.214-0400    [........................] 
[DB_NAME].[collection_name] 0B/4.28MB (0.0%)
2019-05-19T20:54:55.782-0400    [........................] [DB_NAME].[collection_name]  0B/4.28MB (0.0%)
2019-05-19T20:54:55.782-0400    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
2019-05-19T20:54:55.782-0400    imported 0 documents
```

I'm getting the host URI from the Atlas 'connect your application' provided URI.  I've ensured I have IP white list enabled (and also tried using 0.0.0.0/0), and have the user setup for full admin access.

How can I achieve an import into the cluster, the free tier doesn't seem to indicate any limitations where importing is concerned.

I also just realized that when I try to connect via shell, I get the response:

```
Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 21 checks in a row.
```